# Apply unique images by attribute to each sku magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, attributes, programmatically

In magento2 - How can I perform this task through a script?

[image]

I already relate the configurations to the product with this segment

```
$attributeModel = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
if ($attSetId == self::DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID) {
    $attributes = array(self::ATTRIBUTE_ID_SIZE, self::ATTRIBUTE_ID_COLOR);
} else {
    $attributes = array(self::ATTRIBUTE_ID_COLOR);
}
$associatedProductIds = array_keys($variants);
if ($isNew) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
        echo "Setting attribute $attributeId\n";
        $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $product->getId(), 'position' => $position);
        $position++;
        $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
    }
}
echo "Setting affected configurable product attributes\n";
try {
    $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes($attSetId);
    $this->objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributes($product, $attributes);
    $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId($attSetId);
    $product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds); // Setting Associated Products
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->setImageFromChildProduct($product);
    $product->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I'm a little bit lost with the images by colour.

Thanks in advance.